# Show this Runge-Kutta method is order 3

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

We have been asked to prove the following Runge-Kutta method is of order 3

$y_{i+1} = y_i + \frac{K_1}{4} + \frac{3K_3}{4}$

with

$K_1 = h \times f(x_i,y_i)$

$K_2 = h \times f(x_i + \tfrac{h}{3}, y_i + \tfrac{K1}{3})$

$K_3 = h \times f(x_i + \tfrac{2h}{3}, y_i + \tfrac{2K_2}{3})$

We have ideas from this answer -[Determining Runge-Kutta Order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005711/determining-runge-kutta-order) - but are struggling to apply our system to this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man the Butcher tables are named after (see these [slides](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf)), the conditions for order 3 are
\begin{align}
b_1+b_2+b_3&=1\\
b_2c_2+b_3c_3&=\frac12\\
b_2c_2^2+b_3c_3^2&=\frac13\\
\text{and}\quad
b_3a_{32}c_2=\frac16
\end{align}
which gives $$b_2c_2(c_3-c_2)=\frac12c_3-\frac13$$ which for $c_2=\frac13$ and $c_3=\frac23$ results in $b_2=0$ and $b_3=\frac34$ which finally has $b_1=\frac14$, $a_{32}=\frac23$, $a_{31}=0$.

---

$\newcommand{\D}{\mathit\Delta}$
This is a (the) third order Heun method, as the [type of method Karl Heun (1900)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527302/whats-the-motivation-for-runge-kutta-methods/2527316#2527316) considered were based on combining slope iterations of the form $$\D ^m_\nu y = f(x+ε^m_\nu\D x,y+ε^m_\nu\D ^{m+1}_\nu y)\D x,~~~ m=0,...,s_\nu$$ with $ε^{s_\nu}_\nu=0$ into a final update $$\D y=\sum \alpha_\nu\D ^0_\nu y.$$ This third order method [Heun, p. 30](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma01runggoog/page/n40) gave as

> und hieraus resultiert die für die Anwendungen sehr bequeme Formel
> $$
> IV)\quad\left\{\begin{aligned}
> \D y &= \frac14\left\{f(x,y)+3f\left(x+\frac23\D x,y+\D 'y\right)\right\}\cdot\D x\\
> \D 'y &= \frac23f\left(x+\frac13\D x,y+\frac13f\cdot\D x\right)\cdot\D x
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$