# Third-order Runge Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Prove that the third-order Runge-Kutta method reproduces the Taylor series of the solution up to and including terms inh3for any differential equations.

$$x(t+h) =x(t) + \frac19 (2 K_1 + 3 K_2 + 4 K_3)$$

where

$$\begin{aligned} K_1 &= h f(t,x)\\ K_2 &= h f \left(t + \frac12 h, x + \frac12 K_1 \right)\\ K_3 &= h f \left(t + \frac34 h, x + \frac34 K_2 \right)\end{aligned}$$

I am really struggling with proving this. I need any help for that. Thank you.

Comment: So, what have you done so far? At what point are you struggling?

Comment: I have found, x^(''),and x^('''),

Comment: I consider x^(')=f(t,x) to be any DE. Then, x^('')=(f_t+f_x .f,  and x^(''')=f_tt+f_xx.f+f_x(f_t+f_x.f) where f=x^'=f(t,x). And I wanted to find K2,K3, by using a Tylor series of order 3 but I am having troble with very long term that I found?

Comment: Dear OP, if you are still looking for an answer, I have answered on a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957088/a-question-regarding-runge-kutta-method-of-order-3/3958591#3958591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Butcher tableau for the given method is
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}c&A\\\hline&b\end{array}
\qquad=\qquad
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0&\\
\frac12&\frac12\\
\frac34&0&\frac34\\
\hline
&\frac29&\frac39&\frac49
\end{array}
$$
For 3-stage methods you get order conditions (see for instance [Butcher 2008](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ebutcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf))
\begin{align}
\text{order $1$}&:& b_1+b_2+b_3&=1\\
\text{order $2$}&:&  b_2c_2+b_3c_3&=\tfrac12\\
\text{order $3$}&:&  b_2c_2^2+b_3c_3^2&=\tfrac13\\
 & &  b_3a_{32}c_2&=\tfrac16\\
\end{align}

It can be easily checked that these conditions are satisfied.