# Exercise with Runge Kutta Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

I have this exercise that I can't solve. could someone explain me step by step how to solve it?

We consider an ordinary differential equation of the form

$x(a) = x_{0} \\
x′(t) = f (t, x(t)) t ∈ [a, b]$

Determine the real-valued parameters $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$ such that the three-level Runge Kutta procedure
$$\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
c_{2} & c_{2} \\
c_{3}& 0& c_{3}\\
\hline
& 0 &0 &1 
\end{array} $$
has order 2.

Comment: You need to satisfy order conditions like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531675/third-order-runge-kutta-method/4029232#4029232. Remove first the terms that contain zero as factor.

Comment: Sorry but I really don´t know how to do it. Can you quickly show me?

Comment: The first-order condition is trivially true, the second order condition reduces to $c_3=\frac12$, so you get some extended variant of the explicit midpoint method, the third order conditions can not be satisfied. There are no conditions that bind $c_2$, so you can take any value, like $1/2$, $1/3$ or $1/4$. One could try for an optimized stability region, but that is not demanded in the task.

Comment: However, I cannot understand what conditions they must satisfy. I read the pdf you sent, however I didn't understand much. Could you explain them to me?

Comment: Let's consider only autonomous ODE, this is quite general enough. The combination formula says that $\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}{h}=f(z_3)$, $z_3=y_n+c_3hf(z_2)$. This is correct to order $O(h^2)$ if $z_3$ is close to $\frac{y_{n+1}-y_n}2$ to the same order. This means that $c_3=\frac12$, independent of what $c_2$ is. Of course, the error terms will be larger if $c_2$ is too far away from the interval $[0,1]$, but that was not the question here.

Comment: The order 1 and 2 conditions are simply the quadrature conditions, as the coefficients $b_k$ and $c_k$ must make up a quadrature method of at least the intended order of the RK integration method. In the order 3 conditions, the first one is again quadrature, while the second one could be vaguely characterized as extrapolation condition.